# What does this value of the CssClass property mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
CssClass="validate[required,funcCall[checkDate]]"
```

this is a property of an `<asp:TextBox`. and the page has a js function `checkDate`
im not really sure if its an asp.net functionality or js/jquery,

thanks in advance.

Comment: obviously it calls a javascript function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is jquery validaiton engine function.
check the below link for more inforation:

http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this code is part of jQuery's validation plugin.